# how to disable symbols after dot in double values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, double

How to disable symbols after dot in double values?
13 + 3.456 = 16.456  GOOD

13 + 1 = 14.00   BAD! I need 14   how can I do It?

I am using NSMutableString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([yourString doubleValue] % 1 == 0) {
    [yourString setString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [yourString intValue]]];
}
```

Comment: You may want to change the out rather than covert the value. [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f"];